# Adding additional metadata to the noflo-ui

Tags: elixir, noflo

I am developing a noflo runtime in the Elixir language (more [here](http://www.elixirfbp.org)) and [here](https://github.com/pcmarks/ElixirFBP).

I would like the user of the noflo-ui to be able to specify some node metadata, specifically, the number of processes to deploy for a given component. How can this best be added to the existing noflo-ui? I'm willing to modify the code but wanted to make sure that this capability didn't already exist and that I hadn't overlooked it. If I do have to modify the existing code, where should I start?

Or, is there a different/better way for the user to add metadata?

Comment: Super cool that you are developing a FBP runtime and implementing the FBP runtime prototcol!

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no such functionality, but we definetely want it.
I've filed an [issue here](https://github.com/noflo/noflo-ui/issues/482). Description includes proposed way to implement:

> Add it to the node-inspector card, that appears on right-hand side. The code for that can be found at:
>   https://github.com/noflo/noflo-ui/blob/master/elements/noflo-node-inspector.html
>
> Possible UI could be to have a list of key+value pairs, with actions
>   to add, edit and delete such a pair.